# Can I query SQL Server's word stems?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I know that I can run searches similar to the following to find rows containing multiple forms of the same word (e.g. "hammers"):

```
SET @currentWord = 'hammers'
SET @stemSearch = 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,' + @currentWord + ')'
SELECT @matches = count(word) FROM tblWord WHERE CONTAINS(word, @stemSearch)
```

Is it possible to write a stored procedure (or otherwise get the root of the word, preferably with the same results that MSSQL would return) that given a word in any form will return just the root of that word? (e.g. "hammer" for "hammers", or "goose" for "geese")

Comment: Alternatively, an API or some other service for determining root word would also be acceptable.

Comment: I signed up for and started trying out the [Wordnik api](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs), but unfortunately it seems to do a poor job of canonicalizing. It does 'cats' -> 'cat', but not 'geese' -> 'goose', or even 'humans' -> 'human'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still working out the details, but for now here's a partial solution:

- I created a table and a stored proc that will be used for this. The table has a surrogate key, a column named `word`, and a column named `associatedWordId`.
- The stored proc uses fn_Split to split the input list (e.g. `'dog,dogs,cat,cats'`) into a table variable, and then inserts them into the permanent table (required to get full text indexing on the `word` column).
- Then it loops over the contents of the table, using the `FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, ...)` search, and marks all related words (including matching the search word to itself).
- I can then query the resulting table to group my report data for multiple forms of the same word.

There is one problem with the stored procedure as-is (more on that in a moment); but here is my proc so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_identifyWordAssociations] (
    @words varchar(max)
)
AS

    --clear out the existing data
    delete from tblWordAssociation

    --insert the new words
    insert into tblWordAssociation (word)
        select [value] from fn_splitList(@words)


    --get a copy to loop from
    create table #myTmpTable (
        word varchar(100)
    )
    insert into #myTmpTable
        select word from tblWordAssociation

    --loop over each word
    declare @word varchar(100), @wordId int, @wordParent int, @stemSearch varchar(120)
    while exists (select top 1 word from #myTmpTable)
    begin

        select top 1 @word = word from #myTmpTable

        --get the word information
        select top 1 @wordId = id, @wordParent = associatedWordId
            from tblWordAssociation where word = @word

        --if the word hasn't already been looked up
        if (@wordParent is null)
        begin
            --setup stem search
            set @stemSearch = 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,' + @word + ')'
            --update all other forms of the current word with this word
            update tblWordAssociation
                set associatedWordId = @wordId
            where
                id in (
                    --get words that are other forms of the current word
                    select id
                    from tblWordAssociation
                    where
                        contains (word, @stemSearch)
                    and
                        associatedWordId is null
                )
        end

        --now that we're done with this word, remove it from the temp table
        delete from #myTmpTable
            where word = @word

    end

    drop table #myTmpTable

    select id, word, associatedWordId from tblWordAssociation

GO
```

While this doesn't solve my original goal of getting the stem of the input word, it does solve my immediate need of grouping multiple forms of the same word in my report.

Here's the rub:

The first time you run the proc, it returns all `null` values for the associatedWordId column. If I then immediately re-run it, I get the desired output. I'm guessing this has something to do with timing of the index creation. I tried adding a `select *` after populating the permanent table (`tblWordAssociation`) but before starting my loop, but that didn't fix it.

I tried splitting the stored proc into two: one for the delete/insert, and one for the update + select. When run in rapid succession, this did not fix the problem; however, if I pause briefly between running them, the results are as expected. I believe this indicates that the index requires a certain amount of time to be built. As a result, the only logical thing I can think to do is to have my application scan the results of the 2nd proc for NULLs, and if found, wait a few seconds and try again.

Is there a way to have my proc wait until the index is built before continuing?

Comment: Even splitting this into two stored procedures didn't resolve the (I think) indexing timing issue, but it did allow me to do something along the lines of: `while (isNull(resultset)){ sleep(10); getResultSet(); }}` without re-inserting the data every time. For the time being, I'm using this and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is NO. You would need to have a library of words, their roots, etc. For example you will need to provide the following information: Do 'monk' and 'monkey' have the same root? I would suggest to read about [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx.)

Maybe this will do for you

```
SET @currentWord = 'hammers'
SET @stemSearch = 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,' + @currentWord + ')'
SELECT @matches = count(word) FROM tblWord WHERE SOUNDEX(word)=SOUNDEX(@stemSearch)
```

or

```
SET @currentWord = 'hammers'
SET @stemSearch = 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,' + @currentWord + ')'
SELECT @matches = count(word) FROM tblWord WHERE DIFFERENCE(word, @stemSearch) IN (4,3)
```

Comment: My ultimate goal is to take a dataset of word occurrences in essays (human, humans, humankind, humanity; for example) and aggregate them, so that we can see that the root ("human") occurs 357 times, which is an aggregate of the occurrences for all of the words with the same root. I will try using a soundex function (outside of SQL) but I'm not hopeful that it will serve my needs.

Comment: As I suspected, Soundex doesn't seem to be the answer I need. Here are the soundex values for my sample words: human = H550, humans = H552, humankind = H552, humanity = H553.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the same inflectional forms which SQL Server use in CONTAINS query. SQL Server FTS parser can be called directly using the following function and this function can work with any predicate used in CONTAINS:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "dogs")', 1033, NULL, 1)
```